# I want to perform different type of action based on value is positive or negative

Tags: php, sql

I have a sql database where I want to save values

positive in column called credit in

negative in column called credit out

is there any way that php detect that value is positive I know what to do just tell me how to say php that

> if(value == +ve){ //do this }else{ //do this }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if( $value >= 0) {
    // It's positive (or equal to zero)
} else {
    // It's negative 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To test for positive:

```
if(value>=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(value > 0){ 
    // do this
}
elseif(value < 0){
    // do that
}
```